# How to handle payments for a multi-platform application on iOS?

Tags: ios, angular, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments

I have an application for architects built for use on web, windows, mac, iOS and Android. It also integrates into the standard drawing production software for architects. I am using Stripe to handle payments and invoicing.

My Question is, for a multi-platform application like this, what are the rules regarding payments for digital goods on iOS?

Currently, users can create "projects" on any platform (web, iOS, etc). That additional "project" is added to that users subscription, and they are billed monthly or annually based on how many active 'projects' they have. So it would be very difficult to utilize in-app payments on iOS for projects created there, and Stripe for projects created on other platforms, given that all projects are combined into one subscription.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You must use Apple IAP on iOS. You can use other payment methods on other platforms. It is acceptable for a user to access a subscription that they have paid for on another platform by logging into their account on an iOS device; look at Netflix; on iOS you can only subscribe with IAP but if you subscribe with another method on another platform you can login to your account on iOS and use it.

Comment: Great, thank you, that is what I was curious about. So if I just don't provide a method at all to pay on iOS that is acceptable?

Comment: Yes, you can just provide an account login, but you cannot provide a link to your web site where they can pay from within the app.